# Komplementär-Adjektiv zu "schriftsprachlich"?

Tags: single-word-request

Beim Korrekturlesen einer wissenschaflichen Abschlussarbeit zum Thema Alphabetisierungs-Unterricht fällt (und stößt) mir dieser Satz auf:

> Dabei werden die benötigten sprachlichen sowie schriftsprachlichen Handlungsfähigkeiten theoretisch thematisiert.

Der Autor versucht hier, von mündlicher und schriftlicher Ausdrucksfähigkeit bei Personen zu sprechen. Er stellt *sprachlich* und *schriftsprachlich* gegenüber, wobei er mit *sprachlich* die gesprochene Sprache meint. Das mag im Kontext des gegebenen akademischen Faches Usus sein (Fragezeichen), doch jedenfalls stolpert man als Leser wegen des Ungleichgewichts auf der formalen Ebene darüber.

Das Wort *schriftsprachlich* ist wohletabliert. Was mich wundert ist: Welches Adjektiv könnte man eleganterweise verwenden, um demgegenüber auf die mündliche Sprache abzuheben? Logisch wäre *mundsprachlich*, aber das habe ich noch nie gehört. *Sprechsprachlich* wäre sehr präzise, klingt aber ungelenk. *Lautsprachlich* wäre auch präzise, ist aber schon besetzt, nämlich für Onomatopoetisches.

Wie geht die deutschsprachliche Linguistenwelt damit um? Welches Adjektiv ist nach guter Handwerkskunst zu verwenden, um im Kontrast zu *schriftsprachlich* auf die Verwendung gesprochener Sprache hinzuweisen? <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Auf Englisch täte man sich leicht: *... the required oral and written language skills...* Aber fürs Deutsche hilft das nicht weiter. Kein Mensch spricht ernsthaft von *oralsprachlichem Ausdruck*.

Comment: Ist das überhaupt das richtige Adjektiv? Das Komplement wäre nämlich *lautsprachlich*.

Comment: @Janka - "Lautsprachlich" dachte ich auch kurz, aber für mich hört sich das nach wau-wau, brumm-brumm, oink und gluck an (also lautmalerischem Ausdruck).

Comment: @Christian Sprache ist immer ein Nachahmen vorangegangener Muster. "Sprache" ist trivialer Weise das Zeichen, das Deutsche machen, um die Aufmerksamkeit auf das Denotat lenken. Vgl zudem *schrift, scrape, graph, ecrit* und das durchaus lautmalerische *Kratzen*.

Comment: Es hilft übrigens, dass *sowie* auch *so wie* im Sinne *bspw.* gelesen werden kann. Soweit *Sprache* die *Schriftsprache* nicht ausschließt, ist mir nicht klar, weshalb gesondert auf Schrift verwiesen werden muss, als wäre es etwas besseres.

Comment: Ich bin nicht der Meinung, dass _lautsprachlich_ hier missverständlich, weil besetzt, wäre. [_Lautsprache_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lautsprache) ist definitiv in Gebrauch, um die Modalität von Schrift- und Gebärdensprache abzugrenzen; und genauso ist die Unterscheidung von _Laut- und Schriftspracherwerb_ eine, die mir üblich und unmissverständlich vorkommt...

Comment: Ich kenne den Originaltext nicht. Von dem zitierten Ausschnitt (Quelle?) her, käme auch Denken in Sprache in Betracht.

Answer (score 7):

Ich teile die Ansicht nicht, wonach das Wort «schriftsprachlich» in der Linguistik etabliert sei. Vielmehr halte ich es für unklar, denn es lässt offen, ob nun die <del>Medialität</del> mediale Schriftlichkeit gemeint ist (Schrift vs. Wort) oder <del>der Stil</del> die konzeptuelle Schriftlichkeit (die ungefähr dem Stil entspricht, also gehoben vs. umgangssprachlich).

Ich würde also dazu raten, einfacher und klarer von **«mündlichen sowie schriftlichen Handlungsfähigkeiten»** zu sprechen (falls wirklich die Medialität gemeint ist).

*Nachtrag 2019-05-29: Die relevanten Fachwörter sind* mediale *vs.* konzeptuelle Schriftlichkeit/Mündlichkeit. *Um ganz sicher zu gehen, dass keine Missverständnisse entstehen (bzw. dass diejenigen, welche die Arbeit korrigieren, keine Abzüge wegen unklarer Begrifflichkeit machen), sollte in einer Fussnote darauf hingewiesen werden, dass es hier um* mediale Mündlichkeit/Schriftlichkeit *geht.*

Comment: Das ist zwar gewissermaßen eine ausweichende Antwort (ein direktes Komplement zu *schriftsprachlich* im hier gemeinten Sinne lieferst du nicht), aber die Lösung, wie der Satz besser zu formulieren wäre, ist elegant. Vielen Dank! - Zum Problem, dass *schriftsprachlich* meistens synonym zu *standardsprachlich* verwendet wird: Ja, das ist in der Tat so, aber ich denke, mindestens in Kreisen des hier zugrundeliegenden Faches (Schriftlichkeitserwerb Erwachsener) ist *schriftsprachlich* schon auch noch mit der Nebenbedeutung *schriftliche Sprachäußerungen betreffend* im Einsatz.

Comment: "es lässt offen, ob nun die Medialität gemeint ist (Schrift vs. Wort)" - ist das denn so? *Schriftsprachlich* scheint mir eben gerade kein Synonym zu *schriftlich* zu sein, bzw. hatte ich den Unterschied in der tatsächlichen Verwendung immer klar als "was jemand schreiben könnte" vs. "was jemand geschrie ben hat" wahrgenommen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Jedenfalls der Autor der fraglichen Abschlussarbeit verwendet *schriftsprachlich* hier eindeutig im Sinne von *bezogen auf die Fähigkeit, sprachliche Äußerungen in schriftlicher Form zu produzieren*, wobei das Sprachregister (Dialekt, Alltags-Slang, Bürokratiesprache, Fachjargon, Soziolekt, etc.) hier keine Rolle spielt. Ich weiß nicht, ob der Autor das hier nach den Regeln seines Faches richtig macht, gehe aber einfach mal gutgläubig davon aus.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Damit kannst du in der Tat Recht haben. Das Wortpaar birgt meiner Meinung nach aber allgemein auch die Gefahr, dem Drang mancher Menschen zum Opfer zu fallen, möglichst ein längeres und komplizierter/gebildeter klingendes vermeintliches Synonym zu wählen (siehe z.B. "Begrifflichkeit" vs. "Begriff").

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schriftsprachlich) nennt als eines der möglichen Gegenwörter zu schriftsprachlich

> spontansprachlich

und nennt [hierzu](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/spontansprachlich) wiederum als Bedeutung "auf die gesprochene Sprache, wie sie im Alltag verwendet wird, bezogen".

*Anmerkung:* Ich bin aber kein Linguist und weiß deshalb nicht, ob der Begriff in der Fachwelt so verwendet wird.

Comment: Da grummelt in mir der Einwand, dass schriftliche Äußerungen ja auch spontan sein können. Wie dieser Kommentar zum Beispiel.

Answer (score 1):

(Hier schreibt der Fragesteller)

Nach den ersten Kommentaren und Antworten verdichtet sich bei mir der Eindruck, dass es ein vernünftiges Komplementärwort nicht gibt.

Beiträger Mach hat eine gute Lösung vorgeschlagen, wie der Satz sauber umformuliert werden könnte (siehe seine eigene Antwort), allerdings eben nur durch gewitztes Vermeiden des Wortes *schriftsprachlich* überhaupt, wobei er sich, das gebe ich gerne zu, noch auf das Nebenargument stützen kann, dass *schriftsprachlich* in vielen, vor allem alltagsnäheren Gebrauchsfällen etwas ganz anderes heißt als "aufs Schreiben bezogen", nämlich etwa *standardsprachlich* (im Gegensatz zu *dialektal* oder *mundartlich*).

Da hier aber explizit ein Wortpaar für den Unterschied von schriftlicher und mündlicher Sprachäußerung gesucht wird, schlage ich nun selbst eine Neuschöpfung vor:

> Dabei werden die benötigten **mündlich-sprachlichen** sowie **schriftlich-sprachlichen** Handlungsfähigkeiten theoretisch thematisiert.

Eindeutig nicht zu empfehlen für den alltagssprachlichen Gebrauch, aber für einen sehr engen fachsprachlichen vielleicht eine Lösung. Auf jeden Fall wären hiermit die Wortkonstruktionen wenigstens kongruent.

Comment: Streiche zweimal *-schriftlichen* um Papier zu sparen. Der Leser mit begrenzter Zeit wird es danken.

Comment: @vectory  Klar, das ist offenkundig die Lösung für einen vernünftigen Satz. Aber da waren wir ja schon mit Machs früherer Antwort. Das (vielleicht etwas künstliche) Problem hier ist, dass *mündliche Handlungsfähigkeit* mich irritiert, und zwar gleich aus zwei Gründen: Erstens kann man mit dem Mund auch andere Dinge tun als sprechen, und auch dies wären Handlungsfähigkeiten (Luftballons aufblasen, Essen, was weiß ich). Zweitens reiben sich ***münd**liche **Hand**lungsfähigkeiten* durch ihre Wortkomponenten.

Answer (score 1):

Die formale Asymmetrie nicht zusammengesetzt – zusammengesetzt zwischen *sprachlich* und *schriftsprachlich* ist kein Fehler oder Mangel. Obwohl heutzutage mehr schriftlich kommuniziert wird als jemals zuvor, gilt das Primat der gesprochenen Sprache.

> Sprache und Schrift sind zwei verschiedene Systeme von Zeichen; das letztere besteht nur zu dem Zweck, um das erstere darzustellen. Nicht die Verknüpfung von geschriebenem und gesprochenem Wort ist Gegenstand der Sprachwissenschaft, sondern nur das letztere, das gesprochene Wort allein ist ihr Objekt. (Saussure, *Grundfragen der allgemeinen Sprachwissenschaft*)
>
> Es ist wichtig für jeden Sprachforscher niemals aus den Augen zu verlieren, dass das Geschriebene nicht die Sprache selbst ist, dass die in Schrift umgesetzte Sprache immer erst der Rückübersetzung bedarf, ehe man mit ihr rechnen kann. […] Die Schrift verhält sich zur Sprache etwa wie eine Skizze zu einem mit der größten Sorgfalt in Farben ausgeführten Gemälde. (Hermann Paul, *Prinzipien der Sprachgeschichte*)

Den Begriff *Sprache* würde ich in diesem Kontext mit [langue](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue), also dem Sprachsystem, gleichsetzen. Eine Interpretation als "mündliche Sprache" wäre verfehlt, und zwar zum einen, weil Sprache primär mündlich ist und zum anderen, weil in diesem Kontext die Kenntnis des Sprachsystems kommunikative Kompetenzen herstellt, die unabhängig vom Medium sind (wie zum Beispiel *seinen Tagesablauf schildern, um Rat bitten, über Wünsche sprechen* usw.).

Der Begriff der *Schriftsprache* vereint zwei Konzepte: Das des Mediums Schrift und das der durch das Medium bedingten Besonderheiten. Planbarkeit und Nichtlinearität des Geschriebenen bedingen Gebrauchsunterschiede (z.B. Komplexität und Satzlänge betreffend). Hinzu kommt, daß das Normierungsinteresse sich immer vor allem auf die Schriftsprache richtete.

Ein anderes Beispiel, bei dem eine formale Asymmetrie wie zwischen *sprachlich* – *schriftsprachlich* besteht, wären *Spracherwerb* und *Schriftspracherwerb*. Der (am Anfang ungesteuerte) Spracherwerb geht dem (immer gesteuerten) Schriftspracherwerb voran. Die Sprache lernen alle Kinder, während die längste Zeit der Menschheitsgeschichte nur sehr wenige Menschen Kenntnisse der Schriftsprache erwarben.

Was mögliche Alternativen zum genannten Begriffspaar angeht: Will man das Medium kontrastieren, kann man *mündlich* und *schriftlich* verwenden. Für den Unterschied im Sprachgebrauch haben sich *konzeptionelle Mündlichkeit* und *konzeptionelle Schriftlichkeit* (als Begriffe für Pole eines Kontinuums) eingebürgert.

Comment: Ich halte das Zitat für fehlgeleitet. Übersetzung findet zwar immer statt, ob in der Mundsprache oder woanders, aber Zeichensprache, Bildersprache sowie die Schriftsprache existieren durchaus losgelößt von Lautmalerei. Oder können Taub-Stumme etwa nicht lesen lernen? Entschuldige die Suggestivfrage, ich weiß es wirklich nicht.

Comment: Um Pauls Metapher zu gebrauchen: Natürlich kann man sich mit Skizzen befassen, ohne jemals ein Gemälde zu Gesicht zu bekommen. (Gehörlose können sogar sprechen lernen; aber es ist ein Lernprozeß, kein Erwerb.)

Comment: Inwiefern ist ein Lernprozess kein Erwerb? Inwiefern ist der kindliche Spracherwerb kein Lernprozess? Ich würde Herrn Paul widersprechen und unterstellen, dass es eine Minderheitenansicht ist. Die Schriftsprache hat sich teilweise verselbständigt mit Schriften die sich auf andere Schriften beziehen und die nicht gedacht sind, laut vorgelesen zu werden.

Comment: Um aus John Lyons' Buch *Die Sprache* zu zitieren: *Der Primat der gesprochenen vor der geschriebenen Sprache bildet eines der Grundprinzipien der modernen Linguistik*. – Erwerb vs. Lernen hat wahrscheinlich nicht mehr viel mit der Frage zu tun, daher verweise ich auf [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spracherwerb): *Erwerb bedeutet stets unbewusste und implizite Vorgänge in natürlicher Umgebung […] Sprachenlernen hingegen erfolgt bewusst, ist explizit und wird gesteuert […]*.